# Javascript Submit Button Random Coin Toss

Tags: javascript, html, random, coin-flipping

Hopefully this is a quick fix. I have a coin toss generator that functions correctly (yay!) But I would like to be able to hit the flip button multiple times and run the function without having to reload and refresh the page.

```js
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;

document.getElementById("flip").onclick = function(junction){
  if(randomNumber == 1){
    document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "Heads!";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "Tails!";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Heads or Tails</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Will it be heads or tails?</h1>
    <h3 id="response"></h3>
    <button id="flip" type="button">Let's Flip!</button>
</body>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Just remove document.getelement... & replace it with function junction(){}. It will work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at that code snippet, it works!

```js
function junction(){
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
  
  if(randomNumber == 1){
    document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "Heads!";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "Tails!";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Guess the Number!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Guess the Number!</h1>
    <p>See if you can guess the number between 1 and 50</p>
    <label for="guess"> Enter Your Guess </label>
    <input type="text" id="guess"><br>
    <button id="submit" onclick="junction();">Submit Guess</button>
    <p id="response"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I copied over the wrong HTML but applied you suggestion to the correct file and it worked perfect! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
function junction (){
var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*2)+1;
if(randomNumber==1){
  document.getElementById("response").innerHTML ="Heads!";
  }
 else {
 document.getElementById("response").innerHTML ="Tails!";
 }
}
```

Declare a function in javascript and call it with the onclick attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you may need to make some changes! In javascript , you are using id flip here    `document.getElementById("flip").onclick =function(junction){` but your code does not have any element with id flip!
Edit and catch up.

Comment: Ah! I copied the wrong HTML when I posted late last night! Take a look now!